# Can't get additional jQuery slider to work on my wordpress site

Tags: jquery, wordpress, slider

I am using the Over Easy Wootheme on a wordpress site which has jCarousel included.

Now I need a tiny text content slider on a different part of the side but they all look broken on the site itself. I tried a couple of different ones (SmoothSlider, SlideDeck). **They all looked great on the preview in wp-admin but won't work on the site.**
So I guess it's a jQuery problem somehow?

Please see for yourself: http://med2heal.com/sliders/

I already tried removing the jQuery call from the head but didn't make a difference.

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I think you may need to wrap your jQuery call to that plugin in a document.ready() handler. The console is throwing an error that your call has no method available which might mean that it is calling the slider before the js has a chance to load.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
  // Handler for .ready() called.
 jQuery('#featured_slider ul').cycle({ 
        fx: 'scrollLeft',
        prev: '.feat_prev',
        next: '.feat_next',
        speed:  800, 
        timeout: 3000, 
        pager:  null
    });

});
```

Comment: I just included that and it didn't change a thing unfortunately. Good thought tho!